# R, continue after error in loop with combination of arguments

Tags: r, function, loops

I created a loop for a rather repetitive "function" or piece of code.

I do a dplyr filter of the data set based on two variables. Then I make a linear model, calculate the means and do a LSD test.

The loop I made fills in the variables in the filter.

```
for(x in c("B1", "B2", "B3")){
  for(z in c(1:5)){
  df <- filter(testb, column1== x, column2 == z )
#rest of functions here
```

The loop works fine. Only problem I have is when the loop tries to filter x: B2 with z: 5, since this combination does not exist in the data set. I get the following error:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

I know exactly why it creates an error, since the factor has column 2 z=5 does not exist.
I would like the loop to continue to the next variable of columns 1 and 2, if this occurs, so go to x:B3 and z: 1.

The code works fine when I use

```
for(z in c(1:4)){
```

But I miss the combinations x:B1 and x:B3 with z:5.

Later one I would like to do more variables from column1, but there will be a lot more mismatching with the combinations of x and z.

Anyone any tips?

Comment: If you know the problem, you can use a logical test beforehand (using `if`), if you only know that there might be some errors, `tryCatch()` might be of help.

Comment: You can put the code line which can fail into a try block: `try({ ... }, silent=TRUE)`.

Comment: @lambruscoAcido, this also worked perfect, thanks!

Comment: Though it is included at the end of `?try`, I'll just call it out: you should check the return value of `df <- try(filter(...))`, with something like `if (inherits(df, "try-error")) { do_something_here; }` to react accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test it without a [reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/9524065), but changing your code to:

```r
for(x in c("B1", "B2", "B3")){
  for(z in c(1:5)){
     if(any(testb$column1 == x & testb$column2 == z)){
        df <- filter(testb, column1== x, column2 == z )
```

might do the trick.

Comment: thanks a lot, this did the trick, been looking for something like this for a while now ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(x in c("B1", "B2", "B3")){
  for(z in c(1:5)){
    tryCatch({df <- filter(testb, column1== x, column2 == z)},
             next)
  }
}
```